# Vagrant commands and other fun stuff

Tags: unix, ssh, vagrant, sudo, git-bash

I have started working on a new set of technologies recently and am having some problems understanding what it is that I am doing.  I am using Vagrant, VirtualBox, Git Bash and a few other new things  (new for me that is) and I was hoping someone could explain what it is that I am doing as I am familiar with Windows commands but not so much Unix ones.

So, part of the new starter guide I have been given says that I must run the following commands

> vagrant up
>
> vagrant ssh
>
> sudu su -
>
> tail -f /var/log/messages

Could someone explain what these all do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vagrant up
```

Creates a new virtual machine as described in the `Vagrantfile`.  See [the vagrant doc](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/basic_usage.html) for more information.

```
vagrant ssh
```

Uses ssh to log you into the virtual machine you made with vagrant up. Must be run from the directory containing the vagrantfile or a subdirectory beneath it.

```
sudo su -
```

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/105367/command-sudo-su)

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

The linux tail command prints the last 10 lines of the file.  The -f flag with a filename appends data to the output as the file grows.  So its a way of seeing the log output in real time as the log is being written to.

You can get help for linux system commands using `man <<command>>`.
For vagrant commands you can use `vagrant <COMMAND> --help`